# copy only values from one sheet and paste to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using below sample code to copy only values from one sheet and paste to another. But here it paste my formula also from source file. I want only value and format(dont want formula) to be copied from source and paste to destination sheet.
how it can be done in google spreadsheet scripts?

```
function copyInfo() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy"); 
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paste"); 
  // get source range 
  var source = copySheet.getRange(2,2,12,2); 
  // get destination range 
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,2,12,2); 
  // copy values to destination range 
  source.copyTo(destination); 
  // clear source values 
  source.clearContent(); 
}
```

Comment: function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paste");
  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(2,2,12,2);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,2,12,2);
  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);  
  // clear source values
  source.clearContent();
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967086/copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-in-google-app-script-and-append-a-row-one-s/44967382#44967382

Comment: Set the option to contents only  - `{contentsOnly:true}` [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options)

Answer (score 0):

I have almost same kind of situation. I have to copy data form sheet "Important work" 'range B4 : M getlast row' and paste it into "sheet 8" below last row
please correct this code ...

```
function copyInfo() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Important work"); 
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet8"); 
  // get source range 
  var source = copySheet.getRange(4,2,copySheet.getLastRow(),13); 
  var source1 = source.getValues()
Logger.log(source1);
  // get destination range 
  var paste1 = pasteSheet.setRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,13); 
    
  // copy values to destination range
  source1.setValues(paste1); 
  // clear source values 
  source1.clearContent(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73569296/717267, I created the following version. That is copying dynamically all table data into other sheet.

```js
function copyInfo() {
   var response = Browser.msgBox(
    'Confirm',
    'Copy all data?',
    Browser.Buttons.YES_NO
  );

  if (response === 'yes') {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // Source sheet
    var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy");
    // Destination sheet
    var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paste");

    // First data row number
    var firstDataRow = 3;
    // Get last data row
    var lastRow = copySheet.getLastRow();
    // Get last column
    var lastColumn = copySheet.getLastColumn();

    // Get source range
    var source = copySheet.getRange(firstDataRow, 1, lastRow - firstDataRow, lastColumn);
    // Get destination range
    var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

    // Add rows to copy data
    let maxRows = pasteSheet.getMaxRows();
    if ((pasteSheet.getLastRow() + lastRow) >= maxRows) {
      pasteSheet.insertRowsAfter(maxRows, lastRow - firstDataRow);
    }

    // Copy values to destination range
    source.copyTo(destination, { contentsOnly: true });

    Browser.msgBox(
      'Done!',
      'Operation finished.',
      Browser.Buttons.OK
    );
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox(
      'Cancelled!',
      'Operation cancelled!',
      Browser.Buttons.OK
    );
  }
}
```