# Copying data script is not working anymore

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using a script in my google sheet that I found here:

[copy data from one sheet to another in google app script and append a row, one small issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967086/copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-in-google-app-script-and-append-a-row-one-s)

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paste");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(2,2,12,2);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,2,12,2);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);

  // clear source values
  source.clearContent();
}
```

When I am running it now it gives me an error:

> The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of
> the sheet.

which wasn't coming up before. Does anyone have an idea why it is doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

The error is in this line:

`var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,2,12,2);`

`pasteSheet.getLastRow()` returns a row number which is at the very bottom of your sheet. Then you consider `12` rows range but the `pasteSheet` does not have `12` rows **after** the last row with content.

**Solutions:**

Add more rows in the `pasteSheet`:

[image]

or you can use [insertRowsAfter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany):

`pasteSheet.insertRowsAfter(pasteSheet.getLastRow(), 12)`

**Code snippet:**

```
function myFunction() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Paste");

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(2,2,12,2);
  // insert rows to make sure you have enough space
  pasteSheet.insertRowsAfter(pasteSheet.getLastRow(), 12)
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,2,12,2);
   
  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);

  // clear source values
  source.clearContent();
}
```