# Copy everything from one column to another in Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to programmatically copy everything (data, cells borders, format (%), color) from one set of columns to another.

```
function myFunction(){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = sheet.getSheets()[1];
    const range = sheet.getRange('A1:C5').getValues();
    const newrange = sheet.getRange('D1:F5');

    sheet.insertColumnsAfter(3,3);    
    newrange.setValues(range);
    [...]
```

Here the data as well as the color are copied correctly to the new location.
However, I could not figure out how to replicate:

- The cell border lines (to draw a table)
- The format of my cells in percentage (including the sign %).

---

I've tried the following for the percentage - but did not worked:

```
const percentageRange = sheet.getRange('A1:C5');
percentageRange.setNumberFormat('00.00"%"');
```

Not sure how should I do for the border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
range.copyTo(newrange);
```

this will copy range completely.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967382/555121

Comment: Thank you @Kos it works fine, except for the cells format. 2 of my columns are in % but it does not appear in % when I copy. For instance 17.00% becomes 00.17% in the newly created column

Comment: Let me know if you have any clue how to solve the % format not being displayed properly. I would really appreciate :)

Comment: just for the record: copyTo copies everything, including format. If you have any other questions, refer to official documentation